# Change text case of GridView Header

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, gridview

By default the case of header text in Gridview is uppercase. I am trying to keep the header text unchanged however so far i have been unable to do that. Since, the header row changes into 'th', i added 'text-transform: none;' style in css and it didn't work either. Funny thing, 'text-transform: lowercase' does changes the text to lowercase.  Any suggestions?

```
<div class="grdDiv">
    <asp:Label ID="lblGv1" runat="server" Text="Item:" />
    <asp:GridView ID="grdView1" runat="server" CssClass="line"/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.grdDiv {
    padding-top: 25px;
}

.line tr th
{
    background: #c5c5c5;
    text-transform: none;
}
.line th
{
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: none;
}

.line tr td
{
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking...if the output is uppercase by default, what are you trying to change it to?

Comment: Try to change `text-transform:none` to `text-transform:uppercase`

Comment: What is the actual **output** HTML text and what should it be? Perhaps you could provide a demo with actual HTML & CSS.

Comment: the datasource is simple sql select. 'Select EmployeeName, EmpID From Employee'. If you look at the column names it is not uppercase however when it get displayed in grid, all the header text changes to uppercase i.e. EMPLOYEENAME, EMPID. @askhil- it's already uppercase and i don't want that.

Comment: Obvioulsy I can't look at column names because I can't see the output but if it's output as uppercase your options are limited. You could use `text-transform: capitalize` to have it appear more natural though.